# Declare properties with the same name as some base class properties

Tags: typescript

I'm extending a module and I noticed when I declare some **private** properties, such as the method `init()`, this error occurs:

> Types have separate declarations of a private property 'init'

I know that what is causing this is that I have a *same* method in the super class, but I don't want to be calling different names just because that one is already taken in a class that I can't even access it for being private!

I declared the method as private, exactly to avoid this kind of things. I don't want to override it, but this shouldn't prevent me from declaring it again in another classes. What's the point anyway?

Answer (score 7):

I think that the reason for this is the prototype nature of javascript.
Consider the following code

```
class A {
    public constructor() {
        this.method();
    }

    private method() {
        console.log("A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private method() {
        console.log("B");
    }
}

new B();
```

What you'd expect is that the console will show `"A"` because in the ctor of class `A` we called a private method, meaning that it can not be overriden by a class (for that we have protected).

But this code compiles into:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
        this.method();
    }
    A.prototype.method = function () {
        console.log("A");
    };
    return A;
}());
var B = (function (_super) {
    __extends(B, _super);
    function B() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    B.prototype.method = function () {
        console.log("B");
    };
    return B;
}(A));
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.method()%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09private%20method()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09console.log(%22A%22)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%09private%20method()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09console.log(%22B%22)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D))

As you can see, the `method` in the prototype of `B` is being overriden with the new function, so in reality the console will show `"B"`.
This is the behavior of protected and not private and probably because of that it's not allowed.

As I see it you have 3 options:

- Use different names for the private methods
- Change the methods from private to protected, it will do exactly the same but at least it will be clear in the code that this is the case
- Use a base class for these two classes which holds only the public/protected methods, and then in the two classes implement the private methods